# Use of epsilon in proofs about diameters

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have been working on the following question:

> Assume that $K$ is a compact metric space. Prove that there are two points $x,y \in K$ such that $d(x,y)=$diam $K$. (Recall that diam $K = sup${$d(x,y) | x,y \in K$}.

Here is an attempted proof (imitating Baby Rudin proof 3.10(a)).

- By definition of sup, $\forall \epsilon >0$, $\exists x,y \in K$ s.t. $d(x,y)+\epsilon ≥ $ diam $K$.
- We also have that $d(x,y) ≤ $ diam $K$ $\forall x,y \in K$.
- Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, it follows that $d(x,y)=$diam $K$.

This proof can't be right since it doesn't require compactness of K (and it's easy to come up with examples where the statement doesn't hold for K not compact). Can you help me understand where it's going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: look at your second point you have $\operatorname{diam} d(x,y)$, that seems fishy.

Comment: Sorry, that's just a typo. Corrected!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's something missing. For each $\epsilon>0$ (for example $\epsilon=\frac1n$) you may find different $x,y$, that is you actually get sequences $x_n,y_n$ with $d(x_n,y_n)\to \operatorname{diam}(K)$. By compactness you can find a subsequence that converges to som $(x,y)$.

A nicer proof is: If $K$ is compact, then so is $K\times K$, hence the continuos function $K\times K\to\mathbb R$, $(x,y)\mapsto d(x,y)$ assumes its maximum.

Comment: Not that it would change anything, but $K$ is compact iff $K\times K$ is compact, and +1 for sure

Comment: Thanks. I understand how the correct proof works (with the subsequence). But I don't see what's missing in my proof. Even if you have different x, y for each $\epsilon$, the second point still holds for each such x, y. No?

Comment: @user65257 the first and the second point always hold. But $\varepsilon>0$ so normally you can't conclude that $d(x,y)=\operatorname{diam}(K)$

Comment: Here is the proof in Rudin I refer to. How come the epsilon trick works in one case but not the other? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1802579/Rudin3.10.png (thanks again!)

Comment: Do you have any thoughts, @DominicMichaelis?

Comment: @user65257 there you already have the points. The proof wroks a bit like you know that for every element of the closure of $E$ there is  a $p \in E$ which is arbitrary near at it. so there the existence of the point is given from the definition of closure. Here you don'T have that

Comment: @DominicMichaelis But here we already have the points by the definition of sup, don't we?

Comment: nope if we would have maximum you would have the points, but not with sup.

Answer (score 1):

You say in point three, that there is a $x,y$ such that $d(x,y)=\operatorname{diam} K$. 
You can't conclude that one. But maybe you can show that $d(x,y)$ is continuous and what do you know about continuous functions and compact sets?